# Meanings of some macros in beamer source

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

In the source file `beamerbasetoc.sty` of `beamer` package there are these lines:

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\beamer@tableofcontents}{\beamer@tableofcontents[]}}
\def\beamer@tableofcontents[#1]{%
  \def\beamer@toc@cs{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@os{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@css{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@oss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@ooss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@csss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@osss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@oosss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@ooosss{show}%
  \beamer@showpartnumber=\c@part%
  \beamer@pausesectionsfalse%
  \beamer@pausesubsectionsfalse%
  \def\beamer@tocsections{<*>}%
  \setkeys{beamertoc}{firstsection=1}%
  \setkeys{beamertoc}{#1}%
  \vspace*{-.5em}{\makeatletter%
    \pause[0]%
    \@input{\jobname.toc}%
    \vfill}%
```

What are the meanings of these macros?

- `\beamer@toc@cs`
- `\beamer@toc@os`
- `\beamer@toc@css`
- `\beamer@toc@oss`
- `\beamer@toc@ooss`
- `\beamer@toc@csss`
- `\beamer@toc@osss`
- `\beamer@toc@oosss`
- `\beamer@toc@ooosss`

I guess `s` stands for `section`, `ss` for `subsection`, and `sss` for `subsubsection`. But what about `c` and `o`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer

`c` for current, `o` for other. The macros are used for the default values for the style of the sectional unit entries in `beamer` ToCs.

### Not so short answer

`beamer` allows to apply some effects to the entries in ToCs. Entries can appear as they usually do in a standard class in a regular way (this is called the `show` style) or thay can appear in a semi-transparent way (this is called the `shaded` style), or they can not appear at all (the `hide` style).

The code in the question shows the macros that control the style for sections, subsections and subsubsections in `beamer` ToCs.

For sections you have two possibilities to select a style: one for the current section (`cs`) and another one for other sections (`os`).

For subsecions you have three possibilities for styles: one for the current subsection (`css`); another one for other subsections within the current section (`oss`), and another one for subsections within other sections (`ooss`).

For subsubsecions you have four possibilities for the styles: one for the current subsubsection (`csss`); another one for susubsections within the current subsection (`osss`), another one for other subsubsections within other subsections (`oosss`) and another one for the other subsections (`ooosss`).

For each of those possibilities you can select one of the styles `show`, `hide` or `shaded`.

The code in your question gives the default values for the styles. For example, the line

```
\def\beamer@toc@css{show}%
```

is used to set `show` as the default style for the current subsection; the style is stored in `\beamer@toc@css`.

You can change the defualt settings using the `sectionstyle`, `subsectionstyle`, `subsubsectionstyle` keys in the optional argument for `\tableofcontents`. For example, you could say

```
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded]
```

and this will cause the current section to appear on `show` style, while other sections will have the `shaded` style (you can, of course, also customize those styles).

There are some shorthands for some of the style definitions: for example,

```
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
```

is the same as

```
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded]
```

Those shorthands and additional information about the styles are described in Section **10.5 Adding a Table of Contents** of the `beamer` manual.

Comment: Then he realized that he needs to write `pgfkeys` ;)